# Book Search: Kids who perform space-jumps with their minds

Tags: story-identification

I’ve had a list of unfinished series I have started to remember.

This book is also from within the last decade or so, but I read it maybe four years ago. It is fairly new, in the YA or juvenile sci-fi or fiction areas. It covers the story of a young man in a futuristic society. The society had eliminated the genetics for ADD, ADHD, and other factors that affect genetic/psychological makeup. Due to later scientific discovery, Humans with “irregularities” (ADD, OCD, etc) were found to be capable of performing “quantum leaps” with minimal technological aid. In essence , they didn’t need a computer to pull all their bits back together after molecular transport, though they did have a device that aided them in some capacity (I’m unsure about this). Soon thereafter, that genetic information is selectively reintroduced into specific bloodlines. The main character is one such recipient of those genes, and begins to attend an academy for kids with similar skills when he turns into a teen/tween. He is placed in a group called a pod, where they compete against other pods for ranking (?) 
In short, he is depicted as growing an attraction to a blonde member of his pod who is mute, and the pod members infiltrate an alien ship (there are a wide variety that the humans interact with, but this species appears to be unfriendly) which they disable By uploading a virus into their ship systems.

If any of you could help point me in the right direction, I’d be much obliged!

Comment: It's too old, but a lot of the details reminds me of Kevin O'Donnell, Jr.'s *The Journeys of McGill Feighan*. https://www.goodreads.com/series/56352-the-journeys-of-mcgill-feighan

Comment: Bits of this marry up with the Ender book series by Orson Scott Card.

Comment: Do you recall when you read it?  Possibly anything about what the one or more of the covers looked like

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I'm not sure there's enough space in a comment to list all the ways this doesn't match the *McGill Feighan* books. :)  McGill is an adult, who adopts a kid, and his love interest is Gina, a telepath...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*Earth Force Rising*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30312833-earth-force-rising), part of the *[Bounders](https://www.goodreads.com/series/137855-bounders)* series of books by Monica Tesler.

> Thirteen years ago, Earth Force—a space-military agency—discovered a
>   connection between brain structure and space travel. Now they’ve
>   brought together the first team of cadets, called Bounders, to be
>   trained as high-level astronauts.
>
> Twelve-year-old Jasper is part of this team being sent out into space.
>   After being bullied back on Earth, Jasper is thrilled to have
>   something new and different to do with other kids who are more like
>   him. While learning all about the new technologies and taking classes
>   in mobility—otherwise known as flying with jetpacks—Jasper befriends
>   the four other students in **his pod** and finally feels like he has found
>   his place in the world.

Note that all of Jasper's fellow podmembers are described as "*neuro-diverse*"

[image]

Comment: That is it! Thank you! @Valorum